Undefined ID with Laravel 10 with VueJS
I have a problem with viewing data based on the id of a user logged with Laravel 10 and VueJS, using session's authentication
Hello, I have a problem with my code. I'm using an session authentication with Laravel 10 + Breeze (Back-End) and VueJS (Front-End) but I can't see the data of user logged.
Here the project on GitHub: (https://github.com/PierluigiPapa/proj-assistenza-clienti)
Front-End code with Vue:
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import { initializeDropin, requestPaymentMethod } from '../payment.js';
import { store } from '../store.js';

export default {
  name: 'AppUser',
  data() {
    return {
      dropinInstance: null,
      selectedOption: null,
      selectedHours: null,
      movimentoId: null,
      user: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

    initializeDropin('#dropin-container', 'sandbox_jy6vfhf7_6xqmd4knh2cjrrz9')
      .then(instance => {
        this.dropinInstance = instance;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('Errore nell\'inizializzazione di Drop-in:', err);
      });

    this.getUserDetails();
  },
  methods: {
    getUserDetails() {
      axios.get(`${store.apiUrlBackEnd}/api/authenticated-user`, {
        withCredentials: true
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.user = response.data;
        this.movimentoId = this.user.id;
        this.getUserSpecificDetails();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Errore nel recupero dei dettagli dell\'utente:', error);
      });
    },
    getUserSpecificDetails() {
      axios.get(`${store.apiUrlBackEnd}/api/user-details/{id}`, {
        withCredentials: true
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.user = response.data;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Errore nel recupero dei dettagli specifici dell\'utente:', error);
      });
    },
    handlePayment() {
      if (!this.selectedOption || !this.selectedHours) {
        console.error('Opzione e ore non selezionate.');
        return;
      }

      if (!this.dropinInstance) {
        console.error('Drop-in non inizializzato.');
        return;
      }

      requestPaymentMethod(this.dropinInstance).then(nonce => {
        console.log('Nonce generato:', nonce);
        console.log('Dati inviati:', {
          paymentMethodNonce: nonce,
          IDLogin: this.movimentoId,
          IDOpzioneRicarica: this.selectedOption,
          ore: this.selectedHours,
        });

        axios.post(`${store.apiUrlBackEnd}/api/process-payment`, {
          paymentMethodNonce: nonce,
          IDLogin: this.movimentoId,
          IDOpzioneRicarica: this.selectedOption,
          ore: this.selectedHours,
        }, {
          withCredentials: true
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.log('Risposta dal server:', response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          if (error.response) {
            console.error('Errore nella richiesta POST:', error.response.data);
          } else {
            console.error('Errore nella richiesta POST:', error.message);
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('Errore nella generazione del nonce:', err);
      });
    },
    handleOptionChange(event) {
      const selectedOption = event.target.value;
      const selectedHours = event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].getAttribute('ore');
      this.selectedOption = selectedOption;
      this.selectedHours = selectedHours;
      console.log('Opzione selezionata:', selectedOption);
      console.log('Ore selezionate:', selectedHours);
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="container mb-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mt-5">
          <div class="card" style="width: 60rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                  <h1 class="card-title text-center">Dettagli utente</h1>
                  <h3 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-center mt-3"></h3>
                  <p class="card-text">Nome: {{ user ? user.nome : 'Caricamento...' }}</p>
                  <p class="card-text">Cognome: {{ user ? user.cognome : 'Caricamento...' }}</p>
                  <p class="card-text">Creato il: {{ user ? user.created_at : 'Caricamento...' }}</p>
                  <p class="card-text">Aggiornato il: {{ user ? user.updated_at : 'Caricamento...' }}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              
              <div class="row mt-5">
                <div class="col-6">
                  <div class="card" style="height: 100%;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h3 class="card-title text-center">Form intervento</h3>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-6">
                  <div class="card" style="height: 100%;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h3 class="card-title text-center">Inserisci una ricarica</h3>

                      <form id="ricarica-form">
                        <input type="hidden" name="IDLogin" :value="movimentoId"> 
                        <input type="hidden" id="ore" name="ore" :value="selectedHours"> 
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="IDOpzioneRicarica"></label>
                          <select class="form-control me-2" id="IDOpzioneRicarica" name="IDOpzioneRicarica" @change="handleOptionChange">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Seleziona un'opzione di ricarica</option>
                            <option value="1" ore="06:00:00" costo="5.00">Ricarica Base - 5.00€ per 6 ore</option>
                            <option value="2" ore="12:00:00" costo="10.00">Ricarica Standard - 10.00€ per 12 ore</option>
                            <option value="3" ore="24:00:00" costo="20.00">Ricarica Avanzata - 20.00€ per 24 ore</option>
                            <option value="4" ore="48:00:00" costo="50.00">Ricarica Elite - 50.00€ per 48 ore</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div id="dropin-container"></div>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-login" @click="handlePayment">Paga</button>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
.btn-login {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
}

.btn-login:hover {
  background-color: #194665;
  color: white;
  transition: background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s, filter 0.3s;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
</style>

LoginController:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Login;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'nome' => 'required',
            'cognome' => 'required',
            'username' => 'required|unique:login',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
            'admin' => 'required|boolean',
        ]);


        $validatedData['password'] = Hash::make($validatedData['password']);

        $login = Login::create($validatedData);

        return redirect()->route('logins.index');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $logins = Login::all();

        $totalLogins= $logins->count();

        return view('subpages.users.index', compact('logins','totalLogins'));
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $logins = Login::findOrFail($id);
        return view('subpages.users.show', compact('logins'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'nome' => 'required',
            'cognome' => 'required',
            'username' => 'required|unique:login,username,'.$id,
            'admin' => 'required|boolean',
        ]);

        $login = Login::findOrFail($id);
        $login->update($validatedData);

        return redirect()->route('logins.index');
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $login = Login::findOrFail($id);
        $login->delete();


        return redirect()->route('logins.index');
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $login = Login::findOrFail($id);
        return view('subpages.users.edit', compact('login'));

    }

    public function create () {
        return view('subpages.users.create');
    }

    public function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        // Controlla il valore booleano e reindirizza
        if ($user->boolean_field == 1) {
            return redirect()->away('http://localhost:5174/user');
        }

        // Reindirizza alla dashboard o altra pagina se il booleano è diverso
        return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
    }

    public function getUserDetails($id) {
        $login = Login::findOrFail($id);
        return response()->json($login);
    }

    public function getAuthenticatedUser()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return response()->json($user);
    }
}

web.php:
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\MovimentiRicaricaController;
use App\Http\Controllers\NewPaymentController;
use App\Http\Controllers\OpzioniRicaricaController;
use App\Http\Controllers\LoginController;
use App\Http\Controllers\TipiInterventoController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DettagliContoController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

// Rotte per la vista della home page
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

// Rotte per la dashboard (protetta da autenticazione e verifica)
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');

// Rotte per la gestione del profilo dell'utente
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
    Route::patch('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
    Route::delete('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'destroy'])->name('profile.destroy');
});

// Rotte API sotto il middleware 'web' per gestire le sessioni
Route::middleware('web')->group(function () {
    // Rotte per gestire le opzioni di ricarica
    Route::delete('/movimentiRicarica/{id}', [MovimentiRicaricaController::class, 'destroy'])->name('movimentiRicarica.destroy');
    Route::post('/handlePayment', [NewPaymentController::class, 'handlePayment'])->name('handlePayment');

    // Rotte per la tabella della lista degli utenti
    Route::resource('users', UserController::class);
    Route::resource('logins', LoginController::class);
    Route::resource('opzioni_ricarica', OpzioniRicaricaController::class);
    Route::resource('tipi_intervento', TipiInterventoController::class);
    Route::resource('dettagli_conto', DettagliContoController::class);
});

// Rotta per la vista dell'app Vue (solo per scopi di sviluppo)
Route::get('/vue-app', function () {
    return view('http://localhost:5174/user');
});

// Includi i file di autenticazione
require __DIR__.'/auth.php';

api.php:
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use App\Http\Controllers\NewPaymentController;
use App\Http\Controllers\LoginController;


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "api" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user-details', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::get('/user-details/{id}', [LoginController::class, 'getUserDetails']);


// Cambia la route di post per utilizzare il nuovo controller
Route::post('/process-payment', [NewPaymentController::class, 'handlePayment']);

Route::get('/authenticated-user', [LoginController::class, 'getAuthenticatedUser']);

If I write, I can see the data on Front End:
getUserSpecificDetails() {
  axios.get(`${store.apiUrlBackEnd}/api/user-details/1`, {
    withCredentials: true
  })
  .then(response => {
    this.user = response.data;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Errore nel recupero dei dettagli specifici dell\'utente:', error);
  });
},

